# Multiple drop down form from array in php

Tags: php, forms

I'm attempting to make two drop down forms where the information in the second menu changes depending on the what is selected in the first set of options. So far I have two drop down menus but I'm not sure how to make the second dependent to the first. Any help would be much appreciated. I'm using csv files to store my data. This is what I have so far:

```
<?php
$filename = ("florida.csv");
$csvfile = fopen($filename,'rb');
while(!feof($csvfile)) {
$csvarray[] = fgetcsv($csvfile);
} 

print "<select>";
foreach($csvarray as $row => $arr) {
echo '<option value="' . $row . '">' . $arr[2] . $arr[0] . '</option>';

}
print "</select>";

print "<select>";
foreach($csvarray as $row => $arr) {
echo '<option value="' . $row . '">' . $arr[1] . '</option>';
}
print"</select>";

//print_r($csvarray);

?>
```

This is a sample of what my arrays look like in my csv file.

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => WNDT
        [1] => 92.5 FM
        [2] => Alachua
        [3] => Ocala Broadcasting Corporation, L.L.C.
        [4] => Classic Rock
        [5] => Florida
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => WORL
        [1] => 660 AM
        [2] => Altamonte Springs
        [3] => Salem Media of Illinois, LLC
        [4] => Sports
        [5] => Florida
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => WFCT
        [1] => 105.5 FM
        [2] => Apalachicola
        [3] => Williams Communications, Inc.
        [4] => Adult Standards
        [5] => Florida
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => WOYS
        [1] => 100.5 FM
        [2] => Apalachicola
        [3] => 3G Broadcasting, Inc.
        [4] => Classic Hits
        [5] => Florida
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => WBZW
        [1] => 1520 AM
        [2] => Apopka
        [3] => Pennsylvania Media Associates, Inc.
        [4] => 
        [5] => Florida
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => WFLN
        [1] => 1480 AM
        [2] => Arcadia
        [3] => Integrity Radio of Florida LLC
        [4] => News/Talk
        [5] => Florida
    )
```

Comment: Do you want this to change dynamically while the user is selecting from the first menu? Then you need to use Javascript, PHP runs on the server before the user interacts with the page.

Comment: Good point, maybe I could just have the second form change once the first option is selected and submited. Would that still require javascript?

Comment: You can do that. However, you haven't described how you want the second drop-down to change, so it's hard to give a detailed answer showing what you should do.

Comment: I apologize, I'll try to explain futher. I have List of cities from all the states in the US. Once the state is selected I want the second drop down to show a list of available radio stations from that selected city. I don't if this helps, but this is a sample of the arrays I'm puling from. `[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => WNDT
            [1] => 92.5 FM
            [2] => Alachua
            [3] => Ocala Broadcasting Corporation, L.L.C.
            [4] => Classic Rock
            [5] => Florida
        )`

   '

Comment: So if they select Florida, you use `florida.csv`, if they select Maine you use `maine.csv`, etc.?

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense. I'm just not sure how to write much of what I want to do. I am very new to all of this so please excuse my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

```
$state = isset($_POST['state']) ? $_POST['state'] : null;
echo "<select name='state'>";
foreach ($states as $key => $statename) {
    echo "<option value='" . $key . "'" . ($key == $state ? ' selected' : '') . ">" . $statename . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

if (isset($state)) {
    echo "<select name='city'>";
    $csvarray = array();
    $csvfile = fopen(strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $states[$state])) . ".csv");
    $row = 0;
    while ($csvarray = fgetcsv($csvfile)) {
        echo '<option value="' . $row . '">' . $arr[1] . '</option>';
    }
    echo "</select>";
}
```

Comment: Do I have to change anything? It's just loading as a drop down menu with no options.

Comment: You need to define the `$states` array that lists all the states.